# Error while trying to run Oracle stored procedure using Linked Server in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am trying to run an Oracle stored procedure using linked server on SQL Server.

Stored procedure is `crs.uf` and it accepts a parameter `p_date`.

From SQL Server, I am executing it like this:

```
EXECUTE ('begin crs.uf("2016-02-26"); end;') AT LServer
```

I'm getting this error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LServer" returned message "ORA-06550: line 1, column 47:
>
> PLS-00201: identifier '2016-06-26' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored".
>
> Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 2
>   Could not execute statement on remote server 'LServer'.

What am I doing wrong? How to successfully run this stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 DECLARE @dateval DATETIME

    EXECUTE ('begin crs.uf(?); end;',@dateval) AT LServer
```

Comment: Just Curious! How to pass more than one argument?

Comment: EXECUTE ('begin crs.uf(?,?); end;',@dateva1,@dateval2) AT LServer